# XGBoost regression RMSE individual prediction

Tags: regression, prediction, xgboost

I have a simple regression problem with two independent variables and one dependent one. I tried linear regression from statsmodels and sk-learn, but I get the best results (R ^ 2 and RMSE) with XGBoost regressor.

On the new data set, RMSE is still in line with earlier results, but individual predictions are very different.

For example, the RMSE is 1000, and individual predictions vary from 20 to 3000. Thus, predictions are either almost perfectly accurate or strongly deviate in a few cases, but i don't know why is that.

My question is what is the cause of such variations in individual predictions?

Answer (score 1):

When testing your model with new data, it's normal to get some of the predictions wrong. Since RMSE is 1000 it means that, on average, the root of the difference between the actual and predicted values is 1000. You can have values that are predicted very well, as well as values that give a very large squared error. The reason for this could be *overfitting*. It could also be that the new data set contains data that is very different from the data the model was trained on. But since the RMSE is in line with earlier results, I understand that RMSE was around 1000 on the training set as well. Therefore I don't necessarily see a problem with the test set. What I would do is go through the preprocessing steps for the training data and make sure they're done correctly:

- standardize the data and remove possible skewness
- check for collinearity between independent variables (you only have 2, so it should be easy to do)
- check to see if independent variables have an acceptable variance. If your variables don't vary too much for each new data point it could be that they are useless for explaining the dependent variable.

BTW, what is the R2 score for your regression? It should tell you how much of the variability of the target variable is explained by your model. A low R2 score should indicate that the regressors used aren't very useful in explaining your target variable.

You can use the *sklearn* function [StandardScaler()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) to standaredize the data.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I have significant multicollinearity (wif> 10) in the set, and some heteroskedasticity, which is why I gave up the classic statistical linear regression (OLS statsmodel) and applied XGBoost. As far as I know, the flaws of linear regression such as multicollinearity and heteroskedasticity are not a problem for the predictive power of the XGBoost regressor? R ^ 2 for statsmodel OLS is 0.90, RMSE is 3300. For XGBost R ^ 2 = 0.99 and RMSE is 1114 (with default parameters), with K-fold cross validation the average score is 0.95.

Comment: You are correct, when using XGBoost, or any other tree-based method, collinearity is not a problem. However, it is good practice to remove redundant features. What I think is a clear indication of overfitting is the very high R2 score though (0.99 and 0.95 k-fold). This indicates that your explanatory variables explain the target variable extremely well (99% of variability explained), but run the risk of not extrapolating very well to data the model has never seen before. Is your test data (the "new" data) a subset of the data you trained the model on?

Comment: I think that in this case, the main metric is RMSE, because it is about predicting the weight of ships. It is unlikely that an RMSE of 1000 (tons) is too small an error as a result of overfitting. That's why I don't worry much about R ^ 2, which is 0.99, because the nature of the problem is such that it's not such a great result, considering that it offers an average 'miss' of 1000 tons, which is not very good. Also, as far as I know, XGBoost is resistant to overfitting. What worries me are the deviations in individual predictions, individual MSEs are like: [5,1500,12,3,50,4200,30,3150,150].

Comment: I forgot to mention that the testing was done on a brand new set that the model didn’t ‘see’. However, this new set is very small, 8 lines. The differences in RMSE are very small compared to the model. Of course, individual predictions still vary greatly for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: I really think you should look into how the XGBoost is tuned so as to not overfit. You need to find a balance between the model working well on the train data (R^2 metric) and its capacity to extrapolate on new data. If the new data's origin is different than the training data, I would make my model less specific but more general. For example, are you getting better results on the new data if you reduce the maximum depth of the trees?